# Translation of coordinates to generalised coordinates

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, differentiation, calculus

The translation form $r_i$ to $q_j$ language start forms the transformation equation:

$r_i=r_i (q_1,q_2,…,q_n,t)$        (assuming $n$ independent coordinates)

Since it is carried out by means of the usual “chain rules” of the calculus of partial differentiation.

$$
v_i\equiv \frac{d r_i}{dt}= \sum_k \frac{\partial r_i}{\partial q_k} \dot{q_k} + \frac{\partial r_i}{\partial t}.
$$

Similarly, the arbitrary virtual displacement $δr_i$ can be connected with the virtual displacement $δq_j$ by:

$$
\delta r_i= \sum_j \frac{\partial r_i}{\partial q_j} \delta q_j.
$$

I am having trouble understanding how the first equation is derived and where the second equations is coming form.

1. I am having trouble applying the chain rule in this context i was wondering if a more detailed derivation can be given.
2. I am having trouble understanding where the second equation comes form (arbitrary virtual displacement)?

These equation are in terms of d’Alembert principle and Lagrange’s equations

Comment: Are you asking whether why we write $r_i=r_i(q_1,...,q_n,t)$ or you have a problem in applying chain rule?

Comment: 1) I am having trouble applying the chain rule in this context i was wondering if a more detailed derivation can be given.

2) I am having trouble understanding where the second equation comes form (arbitrary virtual displacement)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A total derivative of a function $f(x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_n)$ is defined as
$$df\equiv \sum_{i=0}^n\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right)dx_i.$$
In your situation, the total differential of a function $r_i(q_1,\cdots ,q_n,t)$ is given by
$$dr_i= \sum_{j=0}^n\left(\frac{\partial r_i}{\partial q_j}\right)dq_j+\frac{\partial r_i}{\partial t}dt,$$
or
$$\boxed{v_i\equiv\frac{dr_i}{dt}= \sum_{j=0}^n\left(\frac{\partial r_i}{\partial q_j}\right)\dot{q_j}+\frac{\partial r_i}{\partial t}.}$$
Considering virtual displacement ($dt=0$) we get:
$$\boxed{\delta r_i= \sum_{j=0}^n\left(\frac{\partial r_i}{\partial q_j}\right)\delta q_j.}$$

Answer (score 0):

The **definition** of the total differential is
$$
d r_i= \sum_j \frac{\partial r_i}{\partial q_j} d q_j + \frac{\partial r_i}{\partial t} d t.
$$
Dividing both sides by the differential with respect to time we get your first equation (the chain rule):
$$
\frac{d r_i}{dt}= \sum_j \frac{\partial r_i}{\partial q_j} \frac{d q_j}{dt} + \frac{\partial r_i}{\partial t}.
$$